# Using a formula to apply a quarterly fee

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a data model and one of the functions it needs to have is the application of a quarterly fee. I have the vast majority of my model finished but this little detail has me puzzled.

Simply, I need a formula that will populate its cell with the fee if the month is an annual quarter and zero otherwise. Such as the below example

```
Month    Fee
1        $ 0.00
2        $ 0.00
3        $ 5,000.00
4        $ 0.00
5        $ 0.00
6        $ 5,000.00
7        $ 0.00
8        $ 0.00
9        $ 5,000.00
10       $ 0.00
11       $ 0.00
12       $ 5,000.00
13       $ 0.00
14       $ 0.00
15       $ 5,000.00
```

My first thought was to use something along the lines of

```
=IF(A1=a multiple of three,5000,0)
```

Of course, replacing the "a multiple of three" part with a function of some sort. Is anyone aware of what this function may be? As a more strict definition of multiples I've also considered something of the form:

```
=IF(3 divides A1,5000,0)
```

But think this may be more complex than the above option, should there be no direct formula for it.

I have the cells formatted correctly so the numbers will appear as currencies accordingly.

Given a model of only 15 months I wouldn't have a problem entering this manually, however I'm using it to produce a very long term forecast so manually entering the data would be impractical.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this good enough ?

```
=IF(MOD(A1;3)=0;5000;0)
```

Comment: Glad that helped, if you're satisfied with the answer, please select it as an accepted answer.

Comment: I shall do. Just 5 minutes more to wait before it lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

`MOD` is the function you want.  Specifically, `MOD(A1,3)`.

This gives the *remainder* when dividing by a number.  Some examples below:
`MOD(1,3)=1`
 
`MOD(2,3)=2`
 
`MOD(3,3)=0`
 
`MOD(4,3)=1`
 
`MOD(5,3)=2`
 
`MOD(6,3)=0`